# BlueJ IDE error

Tags: java, bluej

Im working through my freshman computer science java lab and I have come across a problem compiling one of my programs.

The question: Ask the user for two numbers and calculate the sum, difference, average, and product.

My code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class userInteger{
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner userInput= new Scanner(System.in);

    double _int1= userInput.nextInt();
    double _int2= userInput.nextInt();
    double _intSum=(_int1+_int2);
    double _intDifference=(_int1-_int2);
    double _intProduct=(_int1*_int2);
    double _intAverage=((_int1+_int2)/2);
    System.out.println(_intSum);
    System.out.println(_intDifference);
    System.out.println(_intProduct);
    System.out.println(_intAverage);


  }
```

}

When I try to compile and run my program, the java virtual machine says it is running but a box doesn't pop up asking for user input.

Comment: You are writing a console application and the input will come from the console/terminal. If you want a popup you need to code one. If you want to ask the user to input something you need to add a System.out.println with the appropriate information. Also why are you pulling the next int into a double?

Answer (score 1):

Open the BlueJ terminal with `⌘+T` (Mac) or `Ctrl+T` (Windows).
You should be able to input numbers from there.

Answer (score 0):

your first mistake is in the lines where you are accepting values from the user.
In these lines you are supposed to keep them in the same data type, if u wish to change the double to an int do it through type casting.but for this change nextInt into nextDouble becuase the variables used are double.

```
double _int1= userInput.nextInt();
double _int2= userInput.nextInt();
```